# Testing user model generated by devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, devise

I generated a model using `rails generate devise User`, and later added a field to the model using `rails generate migration add_field_to_user field:string`.

I want to be able to unit test the validation on this field, but no matter what, the users I create are always invalid. I added the attribute to `attr_accessible` in the model and all.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First find out why your users are invalid. Try creating the user in rails console with something like this

```
test_user = User.new(:email => "me@email.com", :password => "somesecret")
test_user.save!
```

The call on `test_user.save!` will tell you which validation is failing. It's important to include the **`!`**

Comment: I ended up creating all by myself, skipping devise entirely, it seemed too complicated :(

Comment: Ok but just so you know, Devise gives you a lot more than just a login system. It let's users manage their accounts, change passwords, validate new users, etc. **If** you need all these added benefits then figuring out how to use Devise will be well worth your time.